# WP site - stop JS hover-tabs CDN from running on just one page of the site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tabs, hover, cdn

I have a WordPress site, and within the head, I have this CDN:

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/tonystar/bootstrap-hover-tabs/master/bootstrap-hover-tabs.js"></script>
```

which allows the bootstrap tabs within my menu to trigger on hover. 
I also have a single page where I am utilizing tabs that are not within my menu, and I don't want the hover effect to apply to these, but since the CDN needs to sit within my head to effect the menu on every page, it is effecting these tabs as well.

So I am wondering, is there a way to prevent this script from running on just this one page?

Or are there any other methods I can use to make these tabs only activate on click, without removing my hover-tabs.js?

Comment: `if ( get_the_title() !== 'your page title' ) wp_enqueue_script('tabs_script');`

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

in your header

```
if(!is_page('PAGE_SLUG')){
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/tonystar/bootstrap-hover-tabs/master/bootstrap-hover-tabs.js"></script>
}
```

**OPTION 2:**

add this in your functions.php (remove it from your header.php if its there)

```
wp_register_script('bootstrap-hover', "//cdn.rawgit.com/tonystar/bootstrap-hover-tabs/master/bootstrap-hover-tabs.js", false, null);
    if(!is_page('PAGE_SLUG')){
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-hover');
    }
```

Comment: I've tried these but I'm not sure the placement is correct. Where in the header should I put the first if statement? Within the head or body?